# Create random time series with shifts in R

Tags: r, time-series, random-generation

I'm trying to create some random time series with shifts along the series.
Some with normal distribution and the others with non-normal distribution (Log normal for example).
For both I have to decide:

- the numbers of the shifts
- the positions of each shifts
- the magnitudes of each shifts
- the length between a shift and another one

The data is 130 years length (monthly) with all positive numbers (because I want to simulate natural abundance time series).
I hope with a picture you can understand better.

[image]

I've foun in other questions some methods for example `arima.sim`. But I do not think that I can put in my shifts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to generate the series by yourself. Fortunately it is not that hard. Simple ARMA(p,q) model:

$$Y_t=\alpha_1 Y_{t-1}+...+\alpha_pY_{t-p}+Z_t+\theta_1Z_{t_1}+...+\theta_qZ_{t-q}$$

can be generated with simple loop:

```
Z<-rnorm(1000)
Y<-rep(NA,1000)
a <- runif(p)
b <- runif(q)

for(i in (max(p,q)+1):1000) {
     Y[i] <- a*Y[i-(1:p)]+c(1,b)*Z[i-(0:q)]
}
```

It is advisable to use a burn-in period, i.e. generate additional $n_b$ values and discard the first $n_b$, so that the series should not depend on the initial values.

Now your shifts can be a simple vector $S$ the same as the length of $Y$ with $i$-th element containing the magnitude of the shift, if there is one, and zero otherwise. Then the loop can be modified as following:

```
for(i in (max(p,q)+1):1000) {
     Y[i] <- S[i]+ a*Y[i-(1:p)]+c(1,b)*Z[i-(0:q)]
}
```

$S$ can be generated as follows:

```
## Number of shifts:
ns <- rpois(1, 10)
## The length of shifts
ls <- rpois(ns, 10)
## The positions of the shifts
ps <- cumsum(ls)
## The magnitudes of the shifts
ms <- rchisq(ns, 10)
##Shift vector
S <- rep(0, length(Y))
S[ps] <- ms
```

Naturally you need to choose your own distributions, but the idea is the same. 
In R loops can be slow, but it is easy to speed up them in this case with function `filter`. Look at the examples in the help page or examine the code of `arima.sim` for ideas.

Note that for ARMA(p,q) processes the coefficients must satisfy certain constraints. I suggest then to start with ARMA(1,1) model with $|\alpha_1|<1$ and $|\theta_1|<1$.

Comment: I'm not an expert about this, so for me is very difficult to understand. can you explain better the "p" and "q" values and can you give a practical example?

Comment: Take $p=1$ and $q=1$ with `a=0.5` and `b=0.5`. Constants $p$ and $q$ determine the order of ARMA process, which is one of the ways to model time dependency.